# Want to know C# .Dot net MVC Helper Class css file Location

Tags: html.textboxfor

I have made a custom HTML CSS file and pasted in view of MVC. I had successfully replaced all the HTML tags with Helper classes like TextBoxfor, so that it could be tightly bonded with model. But after doing that it is also adding its CSS file, which inturn disturbing my custom HTML browser page. I am unable to trace the location of CSS file related to Helper Classes.
"Can any one tell me where the Helper Classes are taking its own CSS or in which folder does the CSS of Helper Classes are present."

Comment: Please include a specific code example that is giving you trouble.

Comment: I am converting html tag <input type="text" class="inputText"> to MVC helper class